# How Smooth Terrain that uses Multiple Perlin Functions

Tags: java, smoothing, perlin-noise

I have been working on a perlin noise terrain generator for some time now. I have worked on trying to implement multiple noise functions to create different features on the map, however I have run into a snag. The edges between the different perlin noise functions are unnaturally harsh. The coloring is dependent on the value of the noise, and I am looking to try to smooth out the values along the border to create a more realistic look. I can find the problematic border areas, but I don't know where to go from there. How would I go about smoothing it?

If it is any help, I determine which perlin noise function to use by the following if statements:

```
if(perlin[i][j] < .22){
    finalHeightMap[i][j] = seaPerlin[i][j];
}
else if(perlin[i][j] > .22 && perlin[i][j] < .28){
    finalHeightMap[i][j] = plainsPerlin[i][j];
}
else{
    finalHeightMap[i][j] = mountainousPerlin[i][j];
}
```

[image: Generation without borders]

Here are the borders that are harsh:
[image: Generation with borders]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried some sort of interpolation or averaging mechanism around those edges? If you can detect the edges I assume you can also detect the surrounding values.

Comment: Yes, I have tried averaging the two points it is around:`(finalHeightMap[i][j] + finalHeightMap[i][j-1])/2` However, this actually was the code used to generate both images, but it doesn't seem to make a difference from the original.

Comment: You may need to average more than just 2 points around it to notice an effect. I was thinking of a wider average on the area. Check out some of the links on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge-preserving_smoothing

Comment: Is the coloring "harsh" there because you effectively have cliffs in your terrain? It looks like you would have big discontinuities in height, given your code, but maybe you've made some adjustments to the various height maps.

Comment: @erickson Yes, I effectively have cliffs in my terrain, and I am trying to fix those large discontinuities.

Comment: And how are the 3 different terrains really different? Why not just have one map (which has no discontinuities), and color that? Do the different terrains have different smoothness or something? If so, could you multiply or the `perlin` map with one of the other maps, which is chosen by the `perlin` elevation? That would enforce continuity, but include some of the texture characteristics of the other mountain, sea, or plains.

Comment: So, I did start with the one map. However, I only got a central mountain, and I wanted something more like mountain ranges. So, to achieve this, I created the different types of noise. The mountainous terrain uses ridged perlin noise, while the plains terrain uses a smooth version of normal perlin.  I also tried multiplying the `perlin` value by the type of terrain, which still gave me the initial cliffs.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume here you know how to find the boundaries in code, given they are highlighted above.  I would recommend applying a Gaussian Blur to each of the pixels around the edges.  You can use this [here](http://blog.ivank.net/fastest-gaussian-blur.html).  For a demonstration on how they would look, scroll down in that page.

Basically, just create an array of pixel coordinates of each of the edges, then traverse that array applying the blur to each.

Pseudo:

```
foreach (Location in Boundary)
    blur(location, radius)
end
```

Comment: So, as I understand, this would blur the map along the boundary, which is what I am looking for. However, if I just used pixel values and applied a blur, I would end up with a discrepancy between my height map and image, which would make it really hard to add in more features. Would there be another way to achieve the same effect using the values from the height map?

Comment: Are you looking for these drastic changes to be smoothed in the height map as well, or do you want to keep these?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for them to be smoothed in the height map as well. By having them smoothed in the height map, it will be smoothed in the final product.

Comment: I would recommend constructing an image as you want it, using Gaussian blur where necessary, then treating it as a height map to construct the terrain.